# NullReferenceException in VB.NET after upgrade to 4.0

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, nullreferenceexception

I have a VB.NET solution that I just upgraded.  It was originally in .NET 1.1, I upgraded to .NET 2.0 and verified that it would build and run correctly.  Then I upgraded from 2.0 to 4.0.  It is still building with no errors, but when I try to run I am getting a `NullReferenceException` in `Global.asax.vb`.  The really weird thing is, the line that is throwing the exception is this:

```
Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable
```

I am not trying to use the variable, just declare it.  Further down a `Function` is called that returns a `DataTable` and sets the variable, but I don't even get to that line.  It is throwing the `NullReferenceException` on the `Dim` line.  Has anyone run across this before?  Is this some issue with upgrading?

*Edit*

Okay, this is the first line in a function.  The surrounding code looks like this.

```
Private Function GetUserRoles() As String    
    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim oDBLookup As New DBLookups
```

I updated it to this, which should make no difference.

```
Private Function GetUserRoles() As String
    Dim oDBLookup As New DBLookups
    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable
```

Now, the NullReferenceException is happening on the new first line in the function.

```
    Dim oDBLookup As New DBLookups
```

The GetUserRoles() Function is the first line in Application_AuthenticateRequest that isn't a Dim or If statement.

```
Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires upon attempting to authenticate the user
    Dim authCookie As HttpCookie = Context.Request.Cookies("GROUPCOOKIES")
    Dim Groups As String
    Dim noGroups As Boolean = False
    If authCookie Is Nothing Then
        Groups = GetUserRoles()
```

I did a Rebuild Solution before posting.  This is a web application and the only files I see in the bin folder are the dll files I am referencing.  I'm not sure what else I should clean up.

Comment: Can you post some of the other code around that line? And are you sure that is the correct line (you may be looking at the wrong version of the file, etc.)?

Comment: If you move the declaration does the error move too? Is the declaration the first line of code in first method executed in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the solution may not have rebuilt properly and is appearing to throw the exception there even though it's actually occurring somewhere else because the source is different than the debug symbols. Try cleaning the solution, manually deleting all your bin and obj directories, then rebuilding and re-running.

Comment: I figured it out.  I copied all of the files to a new folder before upgrading.  IIS was still pointing at the 2.0 bin folder even though I was running the 4.0 solution.  I repointed IIS and it is working.  Thanks for the help!